# How to print a vector of pairs that have as first and second 2 classes in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, printing, std-pair

I have something like this where Client and Order are classes :

```
  std::vector<std::pair<Client,Order>> pair;
    pair.push_back(std::make_pair(Client(2,"Anca"),Order(3,1)));
    pair.push_back(std::make_pair(Client(16,"Maria"),Order(1,3)));
    pair.push_back(std::make_pair(Client(29,"Alex"),Order(10,5)));
```

```
class Client{
private:
    int dateWhenOrderWasPlaced;
    std::string clientName;
public:
    Client(int date,std::string name){
        dateWhenOrderWasPlaced=date;
        clientName=name;
    }
```

```
class Order{
private:
    int amountPizza;
    int pizzaAge;
public:
    Order(int amPizza,int agePizza){
        amountPizza=amPizza;
        pizzaAge=agePizza;
    }
```

And i can't figure out how to print this.I have tried in many ways :

```
void print(std::vector<std::pair<Client,Order>> pair){
    for(const auto& it : pair){
        std::cout << "First: "<<pair[it].first<< ", Second: " << pair[it].second <<std::endl;
    }
}
```

And this :

```
void print(std::vector<std::pair<Client,Order>> pair){
    for(const auto& it : pair){
        std::cout << "First: "<<it.first<< ", Second: " << it.second <<std::endl;
    }
}
```

And in the both ways i have error(first-no operator[] and second,no operator <<)

Comment: You need to provide `operator<<` for `Client`, and `Order`.

Comment: i thought about that but can you write me how this should look ? I have no ideea ..

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: If a complex case fails, look at simpler cases to see where things break down. Are you able to print a vector of pairs of these objects? If not, are you able to print a pair of these objects? If not, can you print each of these objects individually? Don't let yourself get caught up in complexities before you have the basics working. (Looking at simpler cases also helps you write a more focused question for Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt does not work because `it` is the actual pair but `std::pair` does not have an `operator[]`.  Your second attempt is the correct way to go, but it does not work because you have not defined `operator<<` for your classes.

So, simply define `operator<<`, eg:

```cpp
class Client
{
private:
    int dateWhenOrderWasPlaced;
    std::string clientName;

public:
    Client(int date, std::string name)
        : dateWhenOrderWasPlaced(date), clientName(name)
    {
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Client &c)
    {
        // print c.dateWhenOrderWasPlaced and c.clientName to os as needed...
        return os;
    }
};

class Order
{
private:
    int amountPizza;
    int pizzaAge;

public:
    Order(int amPizza, int agePizza)
        : amountPizza(amPizza), pizzaAge(agePizza)
    {
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Order &o)
    {
        // print o.amountPizza and o.pizzaAge to os as needed...
        return os;
    }
};

void print(const std::vector<std::pair<Client,Order>> &pair)
{
    for(const auto& it : pair)
    {
        std::cout << "First: " << it.first << ", Second: " << it.second << std::endl;
    }
}
```